# R squared statistic in predictions of returns

Tags: returns, regression, prediction, statistical-significance

My question is related to an article which use predictive linear regression for the stock returns. There is told that R squared statistic of 1.6% is high. How can we measure which R squared is high? I am confused because I know that R squared statistic should be between 0 and 100 percents.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes $R^2$ is between 0% and 100% but in stock market prediction (which is a difficult task) it is always close to 0, maybe a few percent if you are lucky. Also keep in mind that $R^2=0.016$ means correlation i.e. $r=0.1265$ which maybe looks better to you.

Comment: Thank you! So, if I have a linear regression and $R^2$ is calculated and $> 1.6 % $, this is statistically significant?

Comment: You can see if it is significant or not with the F test. It depends on the number of observations and number of regressors. Usually the program which computes the $R^2$ also computes the $F$ value.

Answer (score 2):

The goal of regression is to account for the variance in $y$. If you are able to do that, then your predictions of the conditional mean of $y$ (conditioned on the values of your features) will be better than if you were to predict $\bar y$ every time. When $R^2$ is positive, even if just slightly, it means that you are accomplishing that goal (assuming mode validation to examine for overfitting). You have a better model than the quant team that always predicts $\bar y$.

Even in [the cases where $R^2$ lacks its interpretation as the proportion of variance explained](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551915/interpreting-nonlinear-regression-r2), a positive value (on a model that has been shown, one way or another, not to suffer from bad overfitting) indicates that the amount by which your model misses are, in some sense, on average smaller than they would be if you always predicted $\bar y$.

To determine if that is enough to profit will be a different story that will involve the money amounts at stake as well as issues external to the asset price prediction, such as trading fees. This gets into the practical significance of your model performance, which might be nil if you can’t make money, even if the model, as shown by something like an F-test in the OLS setting, has an $R^2$ that is statistically significantly greater than $0$.

A danger that I see with $R^2$ is that it can get us thinking like grades in school, where we all want A-grade models with $R^2>0.9$. For difficult problems, that might be a ridiculous standard, and it might be the case that $R^2=0.016=1.6\%$ is pretty good (think of something like the Putnam competition where even one point out of the possible $120$ is pretty good). Conversely, for an easy task, $R^2=0.9$ might be rather pedestrian performance, despite looking like an A-grade in school.

Comment: Hi: I wouldn't use statistical significance as a performance criteria if you're working with return predictions because lack of statistical significance does not imply lack of profitability. It is possible for you to have an R squared  that is not statistically significant and yet the overall strategy can still be profitable.

Comment: @ markleeds What in my answer suggests that? I would like to edit to clarify.

Comment: Nothing. I should have put the comment somewhere else because I didn't meant to make it seem like I was replying to yours. I was more replying to what the OP I think is trying to do so my apologies for implying that.